# How to add a user into multiple cognito groups at once inside an AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Currently we have the function `AdminAddUserToGroup` in Cognito. Unfortunately it can only add one group at a time. Let's say upon signup, I need to add the user to about 10 groups. For this I have to call the function 10 times. So, my question is, is there one function which can do this in one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. The SDK merely uses the APIs provided by AWS. There is no API that lets you add user to multiple groups in a single call. You will need to use a loop and make multiple calls.